# Recursion and Stack in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on stack and recursion. Let say I have a method like this:

```
public class RecursionStack {
    public String countIterative(int from, int to) {
        // do something? Use a loop?
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me like how can I return a string from the number given to the number given (using a loop?) So when I print out it will looks something like

```
System.out.print(RecursionStack.count( 5, 11 ));
prints: 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try anything by yourself? A recursive method is one which calls itself. All recursive functions must have a base condition which terminates this looping behavior, and a recursive definition which calls the method itself. Google some examples on recursive problems, and then try to define one for yourself. If after trying you run into some problem, then come back here with your particular problem and ask for suggestion!

Comment: What's the issue? It's like looping from `from` to `to`, and printing each index value. Should be simple.

Comment: thank you for all your advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive method is one that calls itself. Also, you can't call a non-static method without an instance of the class. You could write an iterative version like,

```
public static void countIterative(int from, int to) {
    for (; from <= to; from++) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", from);
    }
}
```

and a recursive version like

```
public static void countRecursive(int from, int to) {
    if (from <= to) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", from);
        countRecursive(from + 1, to);
    }
}
```

and you might call them like

```
countIterative(5, 11);
System.out.println();
countRecursive(5, 11);
System.out.println();
```

and you would get the requested output.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class RecursionStack {
     public static String countIterative(int from, int to) {
         // the following if is your base case
         // and it is from here that you can stop 
         // performing recursion
         if (from == to) { return " " + to;}
         else { // this else is default and is the basis of the "recursiveness" of the function
             String toReturn = from + " " + countIterative(from+1, to);
             return toReturn;

         }

    }
}
```